# MPAndroid Bar Chart: The height of the bar chart is not proper

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using bar chart in a recyclerview list. in bar chart I am loading 4 data point. but the height of the bars are not in correct proportion.

I used the suggestion as axisLeft.setMinimumValue(0f),axisRight.setMinimumValue(0f) for positive data points and axisLeft.setMaximumValue(0f),axisRight.setMaximumValue(0f)  but in that case some negative value are not showing in the graph.

Please help.

Comment: Hi, please update the question with what you have tried so far.

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa i tried with setMaxValue(of) and settMInValue(0f) as suggested in the forum. but for some graph negative bar is not showing